# Elasticsearch filters on aggregation to return a metric

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of users that installed my apps on Elasticsearch.

To achieve that I doing as follows:

1. querying all the users of interest on index
2. `filters bucket aggregation` to filter the ones who installed android and ios apps
3. `sum_bucket` aggregation to return the total users who installed apps.
4. Javascript to calculate the percentage using the `total hits` and the `total values` within the response.

My question is if there is a way to create a filter **on the aggregation step** which allows me to make only one filter with two conditions and return a metric instead of a bucket, so I can jump the **step 3**.

Here is my query:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "fieldId": "uuid"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "byInstalled": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": [
         {
            "range": {
              "firstIOSLoginAt": {
                "gte": "2020-06-15T06:56:10.436Z",
                "lte": "2022-06-15T06:56:10.436Z"
              }
            }
          },
           {
            "range": {
              "firstAndroidLoginAt": {
                "gte": "2020-06-15T06:56:10.436Z",
                "lte": "2022-06-15T06:56:10.436Z"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }  
    },
    "totalInstalled": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "byInstalled>_count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the response:

```json
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 546,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "byInstalled" : {
      "meta" : { },
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "totalInstalled" : {
      "value" : 3.0
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No there is not. You are doing a count(which is an aggregation) based on a particular filter. If you do not want to do the aggregation you can replace this query by two different queries one with each filter and get the total_hits. But with a single query, you have to use aggregation.

Comment: Ok... I think the best solution then, is to add a new field to my index like firstMobileLoginAt and filter based on this.